# Tax consequences of a gift returned to sender?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, gift-tax, cryptocurrency

**Transaction 1**: On 2014-12-27, I sent a holiday gift of 0.1 BTC (which according to Coinbase was worth about 31.47 USD at the time) from my Coinbase account to an email address.

**Transaction 2**: On 2015-03-28 (91 days later), my Coinbase account received 0.1 BTC (which according to Coinbase was worth about 25.32 USD at the time) with a note stating: "This transaction was automatically returned to the sender because the recipient never logged in to claim it." (And, I never tried to resend it. Ie, I kept it.)

Each is a separate transaction confirmed on the Bitcoin blockchain.

When reporting my taxes, I think my accountant just said we could ignore both transactions. But, I'm curious if that's correct. If not, how should I have reported these transactions on my taxes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would describe this as an attempted but uncompleted gift, with no tax consequence. A gift of this amount would not have been reportable, taxable, or deductible by you. Reversing the intended gift should not be a taxable event either.

(If the gift had been completed and the recipient sold the Bitcoin, the recipient would have to figure capital gains tax.)

Comment: The last sentence should be removed or clarified since basis rules for capital gains on sold gifts are not so simple.

Comment: @HartCO That's why I said "would have to figure", not how to do it. :) It's not part of the question, but seemed worth mentioning because it was a likely consequence if the gift had succeeded.

Comment: @nanoman I read it as, they would owe capital gains tax, which may or may not be true.